# Need help on figuring out the mistakes made in the formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently working on a data set to find out the seasonality data. I am using

```
=IF(AND(MONTH($A$4:$A$20742)=MONTH(E5),ISNUMBER(MONTH($B$4:$B$20742))),SUM($B$4:$B$20742),0)
```

and

```
=SUM(IF(AND(MONTH($A$4:OFFSET($A$4,$H$3-$G$3,0))=MONTH(E5),ISNUMBER(MONTH($B$4:OFFSET($B$4,$H$3-$G$3,0)))),1,0)
```

While column A is the date, column B is the data, column E is the month, cell G3 and H3 are the begin row and end row respectively. However, we cannot find out a reasonable answer in order to plot the seasonality chart. Can anyone help me to figure out what's the mistake made in the formula please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your second formula is missing a closing parenthesis. Other than that, since you have not provided any sample data, or any information at all regarding your expected results versus your current results, it's rather difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: We have daily amounts of rainfall (Column B) and the exact date(Column A) [Let's say 4-11-2016], we are trying to use =SUM(IF(MONTH($A$4:OFFSET($A$4,$H$3-$G$3,0))=MONTH(E6),$B$4:OFFSET($B$4,$H$3-$G$3,0),0))/SUM(IF(MONTH($A$4:OFFSET($A$4,$H$3-$G$3,0))=MONTH(E6),1,0)) originally in order to find out the average rainfall in different months. However, we cannot find out  reasonable answers by using this formula.